# Server using boost asio library crashes

Tags: c++, boost, crash, boost-asio

The server I manage uses the boost asio library
But sometimes this server crashes

There are two patterns that cause a crash
The first is

```
02 (Inline Function) --------`-------- : --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- : myserver!mylibrary::CriticalSection::Lock+0xa (Inline Function @ 00000001`3f1ee4a6)
03 00000000`0332f120 00000001`3f35188c : 00000000`0026b150 00000001`3f20fbdc 00000000`0332f1c8 00000000`00000000 : myserver!mylibrary::CriticalSection::ScopedLock::ScopedLock+0x16
04 00000000`0332f150 00000001`3f34f7ef : 00000000`05382dc0 00000000`00002d60 00000000`0332f220 00000000`00000000 : myserver!mylibrary::SendBuffer::PopPosition+0x2c 
05 00000000`0332f1a0 00000001`3f20fdbe : 00000000`05382db0 00000000`0332f400 00000000`00002d60 00000000`00243c30 : myserver!mylibrary::Session::OnSend+0x3f 
06 00000000`0332f1e0 00000001`3f20f8f3 : 00000000`0332f3f0 00000000`05382db0 00000000`0332f400 00000000`00002d60 : myserver!boost::_mfi::mf2<void,mylibrary::Session,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned __int64>::operator()+
```

The source is as follows

```
void CriticalSection::Lock()
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&lock_handle_);
}
```

The second is

```
00 00000000`02bcf628 00000001`3f83225d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : myserver!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_context::work_started+0xe
01 00000000`02bcf630 00000001`3f8372ea : 00000000`00000000 00000000`02f31c80 00000000`00000000 00000000`02bcf7b8 : myserver!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_io_context::post_immediate_completion+0x1d
02 00000000`02bcf660 00000001`3f83fa48 : 00000000`057e2010 00000000`02bcf8e8 00000000`07ee7010 00000001`3f829016 : myserver!boost::asio::detail::strand_service::do_dispatch+0x10a 
03 00000000`02bcf6a0 00000001`3f83f6cb : 00000000`057e2010 00000000`02bcf8e8 00000000`02bcf7b8 00000001`3f83e13f : myserver!boost::asio::detail::strand_service::dispatch<boost::asio::detail::rewrapped_handler<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_context::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,mylibrary::Session,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<mylibrary::Session *>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2> > >,boost::asio::detail::is_continuation_if_running>,boost::system::error_code,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,mylibrary::Session,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<mylibrary::Session *>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2> > > > >+0xd8 
04 00000000`02bcf740 00000001`3f83f2df : 00000000`02bcf8e0 00000000`02bcf7b8 00000000`02bcf8f0 00000000`00000080 : myserver!boost::asio::io_context::strand::dispatch<boost::asio::detail::rewrapped_handler<boost::asio::detail::binder2<boost::asio::detail::wrapped_handler<boost::asio::io_context::strand,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,mylibrary::Session,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<mylibrary::Session *>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2> > >,boost::asio::detail::is_continuation_if_running>,boost::system::error_code,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf2<void,mylibrary::Session,boost::system::error_code const &,unsigned __int64>,boost::_bi::list3<boost::_bi::value<mylibrary::Session *>,boost::arg<1>,boost::arg<2> > > > >+0x3b
```

The source is as follows

```
void work_started()
{
  ::InterlockedIncrement(&outstanding_work_);
}
```

And when I look at the value of boost::system::error_code it returns 1236, 10009 etc.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, would you please let me know?

And I would like to know if this problem is related to the setting of `/Zc:threadSafeInit-`. I am not using this setting now

Comment: 1236 = The network connection was aborted by the local system. `

Comment: 10009 = The file handle supplied is not valid.

Comment: I suspect some object in your call stack has been deleted, but without an [mcve], it's only speculation.

Comment: async_* calls return immediately but the arguments (including references) need to stay valid until the operation completes.

Comment: Occasional crashes when many users jump in and out of the server

Comment: @ilikecat how many threads? Do you use strands?